# Finding the maximum electric field strength above a ring with a hole in the middle

Tags: electromagnetism, differentiation, calculus

I'm doing a problem (not homework, by the way) which asks for the electric field strength on the axis of symmetry a distance $x$ above the centre of a circular disc, which has uniform surface charge for radii of $a < r < b$ and is uncharged otherwise.

I've calculated this, and come up with

$$
E = \frac{\sigma x}{2\varepsilon_0}\left[\frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^{1/2}} - \frac{1}{(x^2 + b^2)^{1/2}}\right]
$$

which I'm pretty sure is right.

However, when I try to work out which $x$ maximizes $E$ by differentiating $E(x)$ and setting it to $0$, I end up with a horrible result which seems practically unsolvable:

$$
\frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^{1/2}} - \frac{1}{(x^2 + b^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + a^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}
$$

- Is there a simpler way to work out which $x$ maximizes $E$ than differentiating the function?
- If not, does there exist an analytic solution for the maximizing $x$ value?

Comment: Yes. That tool is called Wolfram Alpha :)

Comment: I expect that since this is a past exam question, it is solvable sans WA (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us combine the terms containing $a$ and $b$ respectively:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \Bigg( 1-\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+a^2}\Bigg)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}\Bigg(1-\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+b^2} \Bigg)$$

Simplifying this you get-

$$\dfrac{a^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{b^2}{(x^2+b^2)^{3/2}}$$

And you can proceed further.

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I didn't spot this! This gives a horrible answer, but an analytic one at least.